# How long is it okay for a baby to remain on just breastfeed?

Tags: food, breastfeeding, eating

My daughter is now one and half year old and still refuses to eat anything. She seem to be satisfied by mother's milk itself.

Is it okay to remain on breastfeed alone this long, or should we try avoid/stop breastfeeding so that she tries/takes other food?

Comment: While the question itself, is not an exact duplicate, the answers will overlap so closely, I think you will find the information you need on the answers to the question I have linked, with additional information as well.

Comment: You may also find this answer helpful http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/9372/2876

Comment: From memory, a baby is born with about 6 months of iron supply in their blood. After that, they need solid food to add iron to their diet, hence the iron fortified baby food. Breast milk is not enough.

Comment: Correct @dave. The child's prescribed vitamins also have added iron if the parents were using supplements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The World Health Organization suggests:

> "As a global public health recommendation, infants should be
> exclusively breastfed for the first six months of life to achieve
> optimal growth, development and health. Thereafter, to meet their
> evolving nutritional requirements, infants should receive
> nutritionally adequate and safe complementary foods while breastfeeding continues for up to two years of age or beyond.[['Global strategy on infant and young child feeding']](http://apps.who.int/gb/archive/pdf_files/WHA55/ea5515.pdf)

And goes on to say:

> Infants are particularly vulnerable during the transition period when
> complementary feeding begins. Ensuring that their nutritional needs
> are met thus requires that complementary foods be:
>
> - timely – meaning
>   that they are introduced when the need for energy and nutrients
>   exceeds what can be provided through exclusive and frequent
>   breastfeeding;
> - adequate – meaning that they provide sufficient
>   energy, protein and micronutrients to meet a growing child’s
>   nutritional needs;
> - safe – meaning that they are hygienically stored
>   and prepared, and fed with clean hands using clean utensils and not
>   bottles and teats;
> - properly fed – meaning that they are given
>   consistent with a child’s signals of appetite and satiety, and that
>   meal frequency and feeding method – actively encouraging the child,
>   even during illness to consume sufficient food using fingers, spoon
>   or self-feeding – are suitable for age.

Your breastmilk adjusts to the growing nutritional demands of your child but pediatricians recommend solid food introduction by age 1 (if not 6 months) and aren't expect children to be replacing whole meals when they are 6 months - 12 months. I would introduce solids first before the feeding so that she is a little hungry but not starving and demand the breastmilk. She might take the solids better then.

If your child has increased their feeding frequency, the milk might not be adequate anymore so they try to get more to compensate.

Now she must have lots of teeth so I wonder if she will want to chew. Whereas at 6 months, they just learned swallowing without gagging. When my daughter got more teeth, she preferred more texture. I think the period when they are putting everything in their mouth is a natural way to introduce what we actually should put in our mouth like food and that is probably why solids is suggested at 6 months. She is probably ready as well - has a pincer grasp and all that. She just needs a little stronger nudge.